# Webpack and MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, webpack

I have a JS App, that uses MooTools 1.4.5, and it works fine. MooTools is included by using tags in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./frameworks/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>
```

Now I am doing a rework of the project, will use webpack to build the app, and I run into an issue when loading MooTools. This line:

```
require('../frameworks/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js');
```

causes this error to be reported:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Slick is not defined

It seems as if the the require call is not able to properly load MooTools.
Did somebody else encounter this issue? I am not able to figure out why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: Can you get the exact line where it throws the error? It would be interesting to see that.

Comment: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2722 - relevant.